# JAVA JSON-RPC for Litecoin

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, litecoin, java, litecoin-qt

I am looking for Java Json-Rpc for Litecoin or any implementation for Litecoin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Litecoin is a fork of bitcoin you can use `JavaBitcoindRpcClient` to connect with litecoin client and execute API calls.

link:https://github.com/Polve/JavaBitcoindRpcClient

To connect with client, you can use below code :

```
String user = "RPC_USER_NAME";
String password = "RPC_PASSWORD";
String host = "127.0.0.1";
String port = "PORT";

try {
    URL url = new URL("http://" + user + ':' + password + "@" + host + ":" + port + "/");

    BitcoinJSONRPCClient bitcoinClient = new BitcoinJSONRPCClient(url);
    System.out.println(bitcoinClient.getInfo());
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you @AjitSoman . I have went through it earlier but not able to find any example for using it,It will helpful if you can provide few reference for the example.

Comment: I have added connection code

Answer (score 0):

In my implementation the java URL cannot be built with the structure http://username:pass@server:port