# Is there any RPC Java library using which I can call lite coin methods?

Tags: json-rpc, litecoin, bitcoinj

In case of bitcoin there is bitcoinj. but in Litecoin what will I use?

Comment: how to download litecoin wallet blockchain headers in android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JAVA JSON-RPC for Litecoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/64975/java-json-rpc-for-litecoin)

Answer (score 0):

Litecoin has forked the Bitcoinj project so that you can use Litecoinj

Repo's are here: https://github.com/hank/litecoinj

and here : https://github.com/hank/litecoinj-new

I think the last one is the most recent and active repo.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/GENERALBYTESCOM/litecoinj this one is currently the most up to date, even though it's a little bit old too